# ./maincpp.h(4): error: expected identifier or '('

Tags: c++, c, header, extern

```
    #ifndef MAINCPP_H
    #define MAINCPP_H
    extern "C" 
    { void displaylistfun(void);
    void strfun(void); 
    }
    #endif
```

**Don't know why i am getting this error, I am trying to call Cpp function in .c file**

Comment: You should put `#ifndef` and `#define` on separate lines.

Comment: hey, thanks!! Actually, I forgot to click enter here

Answer (score 2):

`extern "C" { ... }` is a C++-specific thing, when you include the header file in a C source file you should be getting errors.

You need to use *conditional compilation* to have a header file that can be included in both C and C++ source files:

```
#ifndef MAINCPP_H
#define MAINCPP_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
// Only in C++
extern "C" {
#endif

void displaylistfun(void);
void strfun(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  // MAINCPP_H
```

Remember to include this header file on *both* the C++ and the C source files (so the C++ compiler knows that the functions are `extern "C"`).